# How to determine similar values around a particular row in R?

Tags: r

## Goal

I want to find the duration of lane changes of vehicles as shown in the plot, using lateral position data. [image]

## Data

Following is the data for only one vehicle:

```
> dput(a)
structure(list(Frame.ID = 526:1058, xcoord = c(14.346, 14.367, 
14.388, 14.419, 14.458, 14.503, 14.55, 14.6, 14.65, 14.702, 14.754, 
14.807, 14.86, 14.913, 14.966, 15.02, 15.072, 15.125, 15.178, 
15.23, 15.282, 15.333, 15.384, 15.434, 15.482, 15.529, 15.574, 
15.617, 15.657, 15.694, 15.727, 15.755, 15.78, 15.802, 15.823, 
15.841, 15.858, 15.874, 15.889, 15.903, 15.917, 15.93, 15.942, 
15.955, 15.967, 15.978, 15.989, 16, 16.011, 16.022, 16.033, 16.044, 
16.055, 16.065, 16.075, 16.085, 16.095, 16.104, 16.112, 16.12, 
16.129, 16.139, 16.151, 16.164, 16.178, 16.195, 16.212, 16.231, 
16.25, 16.27, 16.291, 16.312, 16.333, 16.356, 16.379, 16.403, 
16.428, 16.455, 16.482, 16.511, 16.542, 16.574, 16.609, 16.646, 
16.687, 16.732, 16.783, 16.839, 16.902, 16.967, 17.033, 17.1, 
17.168, 17.232, 17.294, 17.354, 17.41, 17.464, 17.513, 17.559, 
17.6, 17.636, 17.665, 17.685, 17.694, 17.7, 17.708, 17.725, 17.751, 
17.782, 17.817, 17.856, 17.897, 17.939, 17.982, 18.025, 18.067, 
18.108, 18.145, 18.178, 18.207, 18.232, 18.255, 18.274, 18.292, 
18.308, 18.323, 18.336, 18.349, 18.361, 18.372, 18.383, 18.393, 
18.403, 18.413, 18.422, 18.432, 18.441, 18.451, 18.46, 18.469, 
18.479, 18.488, 18.496, 18.505, 18.513, 18.521, 18.529, 18.537, 
18.544, 18.55, 18.556, 18.562, 18.567, 18.574, 18.58, 18.588, 
18.597, 18.609, 18.623, 18.64, 18.662, 18.69, 18.722, 18.76, 
18.802, 18.849, 18.899, 18.953, 19.012, 19.076, 19.144, 19.218, 
19.299, 19.386, 19.479, 19.574, 19.669, 19.763, 19.855, 19.945, 
20.031, 20.112, 20.187, 20.254, 20.31, 20.352, 20.385, 20.412, 
20.435, 20.45, 20.455, 20.449, 20.436, 20.416, 20.39, 20.361, 
20.328, 20.293, 20.256, 20.217, 20.178, 20.139, 20.1, 20.063, 
20.026, 19.99, 19.957, 19.925, 19.895, 19.867, 19.842, 19.819, 
19.796, 19.774, 19.751, 19.729, 19.707, 19.685, 19.662, 19.64, 
19.617, 19.594, 19.571, 19.547, 19.523, 19.499, 19.473, 19.449, 
19.426, 19.404, 19.382, 19.359, 19.336, 19.312, 19.288, 19.263, 
19.237, 19.211, 19.184, 19.156, 19.127, 19.097, 19.066, 19.033, 
18.998, 18.961, 18.921, 18.878, 18.831, 18.781, 18.727, 18.67, 
18.612, 18.554, 18.498, 18.446, 18.397, 18.349, 18.304, 18.264, 
18.233, 18.21, 18.194, 18.182, 18.175, 18.171, 18.17, 18.172, 
18.177, 18.183, 18.192, 18.202, 18.213, 18.226, 18.241, 18.258, 
18.277, 18.298, 18.321, 18.346, 18.371, 18.396, 18.422, 18.447, 
18.471, 18.495, 18.518, 18.54, 18.559, 18.577, 18.591, 18.601, 
18.606, 18.605, 18.6, 18.593, 18.584, 18.579, 18.58, 18.59, 18.607, 
18.629, 18.655, 18.682, 18.711, 18.739, 18.766, 18.792, 18.818, 
18.842, 18.864, 18.885, 18.905, 18.924, 18.943, 18.961, 18.98, 
19, 19.02, 19.038, 19.054, 19.068, 19.081, 19.092, 19.103, 19.112, 
19.121, 19.129, 19.137, 19.144, 19.15, 19.156, 19.161, 19.166, 
19.169, 19.172, 19.173, 19.173, 19.171, 19.168, 19.163, 19.156, 
19.147, 19.136, 19.123, 19.109, 19.093, 19.078, 19.061, 19.041, 
19.017, 18.988, 18.954, 18.918, 18.878, 18.836, 18.795, 18.756, 
18.722, 18.693, 18.671, 18.655, 18.642, 18.633, 18.625, 18.619, 
18.613, 18.608, 18.602, 18.593, 18.58, 18.562, 18.537, 18.504, 
18.46, 18.403, 18.33, 18.234, 18.115, 17.972, 17.806, 17.623, 
17.427, 17.223, 17.013, 16.802, 16.592, 16.389, 16.191, 15.998, 
15.806, 15.604, 15.386, 15.149, 14.891, 14.617, 14.328, 14.029, 
13.722, 13.412, 13.097, 12.773, 12.436, 12.084, 11.723, 11.361, 
11.006, 10.663, 10.334, 10.02, 9.723, 9.453, 9.219, 9.027, 8.874, 
8.753, 8.657, 8.583, 8.525, 8.481, 8.448, 8.421, 8.4, 8.384, 
8.371, 8.36, 8.351, 8.345, 8.338, 8.33, 8.319, 8.304, 8.284, 
8.258, 8.224, 8.183, 8.136, 8.084, 8.029, 7.971, 7.912, 7.853, 
7.794, 7.736, 7.681, 7.629, 7.581, 7.54, 7.506, 7.482, 7.468, 
7.46, 7.459, 7.462, 7.468, 7.477, 7.489, 7.501, 7.514, 7.526, 
7.539, 7.55, 7.562, 7.573, 7.584, 7.595, 7.607, 7.62, 7.636, 
7.654, 7.675, 7.702, 7.734, 7.773, 7.823, 7.885, 7.96, 8.046, 
8.134, 8.213, 8.278, 8.322, 8.342, 8.338, 8.308, 8.258, 8.192, 
8.112, 8.023, 7.927, 7.827, 7.725, 7.623, 7.522, 7.424, 7.334, 
7.252, 7.183, 7.128, 7.093, 7.078, 7.085, 7.117, 7.177, 7.267, 
7.385, 7.525, 7.679, 7.839, 8, 8.155, 8.296, 8.418, 8.519, 8.606, 
8.682, 8.749, 8.82, 8.891, 8.956, 9.012, 9.057, 9.09, 9.126, 
9.162, 9.197, 9.227, 9.249, 9.257, 9.254, 9.251, 9.247), Lane = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -533L), .Names = c("Frame.ID", 
"xcoord", "Lane"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Method

To estimate the lane change duration, I want to start from the row where the target lane number is reported first time. In the example the target lane is 1 and the number 1 is reported first time when the vehicle touches the pavement marking, as shown in the plot. This point can be added in the data as:

```
a$rows <- as.numeric(row.names(a)) # Row numbers
a$lch <- a$xcoord[match(head(which(a$Lane==1),1), a$rows)]
```

For this point I want to find the difference from every other point.

```
a$difference <- abs(a$lch - a$xcoord)
```

Then, comparing the differences in both directions, there will be some rows where  the differences will be quite similar indicating that lateral position was almost similar. The first instances in both directions will be treated as the limits of lane change maneuver.
How can I achieve this comparison part in R? I don't know how to 'move' from `Frame.ID` 929 (this example) upwards and downwards to compare where the differences become similar.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's the best/fastest solution, but the idea is to calculate the differences between two consecutive "difference" columns you created and pick a small value as a threshold to flag that they started becoming similar. Then get the row closest to the time point of the change for each lane.

Note that I renamed your dataset as `dt`. Run the process step by step to see how the process works. If you are happy with it you can make the script shorter by combining some commands.

```
dt$rows <- as.numeric(row.names(dt)) # Row numbers
dt$lch <- dt$xcoord[match(head(which(dt$Lane==1),1), dt$rows)]
dt$difference <- abs(dt$lch - dt$xcoord)

library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(frameIDchange = Frame.ID[difference==0],                # spot the frame ID of the change
         diff_diff = difference - lag(difference, default=difference[1]),   # find the difference of two consequtive differences
         flag =  ifelse(abs(diff_diff) <= 0.01,1,0)) %>%         # flag if the difference of two consequtive differences is equal or less to our threshold (0.01)
  filter(flag==1) %>%                                            # keep only rows with threshold difference
  mutate(frameIDdiff = abs(Frame.ID-frameIDchange)) %>%          # calculate distance of frame IDs
  group_by(Lane) %>%                                             # for each lane
  filter(frameIDdiff== min(abs(frameIDdiff)))                    # return the frame id closest to the change frame id with a difference equal or less to our threshold


#   Frame.ID xcoord Lane rows    lch difference frameIDchange diff_diff flag frameIDdiff
# 1      896 18.593    2  371 12.436      6.157           929    -0.009    1          33
# 2      953  8.351    1  428 12.436      4.085           929     0.009    1          24
```

This tells you that the frame ids where the differences started to become similar (0.01 threshold) are 896 and 953 for lanes 2 and 1 respectively. Obviously the frame id of the change (929) belongs between those frames as expected.

You can also experiment with slightly higher/less threshold values to see how the results change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I failed to find a threshold value that could work for all vehicles. In your answer the time duration is 953-896 = 57 divided by 10 => 5.7 seconds. The plot in the question shows it is about 4 seconds. I fixed the threshold for this case but then it doesn't work for other vehicles.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I guess this is the trick with trying to model how you define "differences becoming similar". Maybe there's a better approach, but it would be useful to try and find the error when trying different thresholds. Maybe it's not feasible to model exactly all vehicles.